# Get user metadata with react-native-auth0

Tags: react-native, auth0, react-native-auth0

How retrieve the user metadata with `react-native-auth0` lib ?

I tried this :

```
const getMedata = async () => {
   const credentials = await getCredentials()
   const result = await auth0.users(credentials.accessToken).getUser({ id: user.sub })

  console.log(result)
}
```

but i get `Bad Request: Bad HTTP authentication header format`